# Powershell keep only one extension file for each subdirectory

Tags: powershell

There is a directory `C:\New` and inside the directory there is multiple subdirectory with text files like

`C:\New\ABC`: abc.txt , xyd.txt

`C:\New\XYZ`: abc.txt , xyd.txt

now I want to keep only one random text file in each subdirectory and delete all other text file. output

`C:\New\ABC`: xyd.txt

`C:\New\XYZ`: abc.txt

here is a script which is working, but it is only working for only first folder and deletes all text files from other subdirectories.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\New" -Recurse -Include *.txt | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Remove-Item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break your code into smaller pieces, here is one way to do it, basically first get all directories and then for each directory get it's files. Then the method for getting a random file and deleting the rest can vary, this one storing all files in an [`ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-7.0) which allows removing items from the collection.

```
# get all subdirectories
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\New" -Recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    # get all files of this subdirectory
    [Collections.ArrayList] $files = @($_ | Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt -File)
    # pick a random file
    $ran = $files | Get-Random
    # remove this file from the list
    $files.Remove($ran)
    # delete the rest
    $files | Remove-Item
}
```

Comment: thank yo so much. it worked perfectly, however, i got an error at the end ```You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:8 char:5
+     $files.Remove($ran)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:8 char:5
+     $files.Remove($ran)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull```

Comment: @Shahpari i see, that would happen if there weren't any txt files inside that folder. Adding `@(  )` as in my update should solve that problem